# How to setup a permanent WMI subscription which includes a dynamic condition?

Tags: powershell, citrix, wql

I want to create a permanent WMI subscription to start a script every time a defined trigger gets fired. Here I would like to react when the Citrix RTT is above a given threshold. Here a regular PS-code sample to get that RTT data (with a filter in line 2):

```
$sid = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetCurrentProcess().SessionId
$rtt = Get-WmiObject -Namespace 'Root\Citrix\EUEM' -Class 'Citrix_Euem_RoundTrip' -Filter "SessionID=$sid"
```

Now when I want to define a permanent WMI subscription I am struggling to setup the correct filter-condition like shown in the above code. Here a sample for a filter:

```
$filter   = [wmiclass]"root\subscription:__EventFilter"

$f1 = $filter.CreateInstance()
$f1.Name = "CitrixEvent"
$f1.EventNamespace = "root\Citrix\EUEM"
$f1.QueryLanguage = "WQL"
$f1.Query = "SELECT * FROM __InstanceModificationEvent WITHIN 10 WHERE TargetInstance ISA ""Citrix_Euem_RoundTrip"" GROUP WITHIN 10"
[void]$f1.Put()
```

Problem here is, that I dont know how to filter by the correct SessionID. Is that possible at all with the WQL-syntax? I do not want to react on an event which is related to a different session.

Comment: Take care of that when you consume the event - if the attached session id doesn't match what you're looking for, simply return from whatever action/function/command/script is executed by the event consumer

Comment: That is exactly why I am asking for hep here.

Comment: Alright, we can probably help with that. How would you pick the correct session ID if you were manually doing this?

Comment: Yeah but that's not going to work with a permanent event subscriber - the consumer process will be launched by WMI in session 0, not the interactive session from which you might be registering it. So how else would you identity the "correct" session to consume events for? By username? Type?

Comment: I used the SessionId as shown in above code snippet (first line). But I just learned from this Citrix-link https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX210783 that the sessionId is not static for the lifetime of a Citrix-session.